# Keyword not supported: 'server' - identityserver

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I was trying to work through the identityserver4 tutorial. the samples keep using sqlite, but I tried to convert over to sqlserver hosted on azure. at that point, i ran into this error.

```
Keyword not supported: 'server'
```

This happens despite the connection string pointing to the sql server, and the seed method referring to sqlserver method instead of sqlite.

```
    //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    //   options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

[there are other questions with the same error, but this is specifically with respect to identityserver]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, there are two places where the reference is made to the sql server.

along with the Seed.cs file, head over to the Startup.cs file. you will find another usage.

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

That will eliminate the issue.